# Knockout select values from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I get respons from controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetItems(string date)
    {
        IList<dough> modelList = new List<dough>();
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "framed" });
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "unframed" });
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "soft" });
        return Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and display it in such way

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Waste</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableWastes, value: Waste, optionsText: 'Type'"></select></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

result

[image]

The main question is how to display items with default values that was getted from controller? What need to fix?

[image]

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetItems(string date)
    {
        IList<dough> modelList = new List<dough>();
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "framed" });
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "unframed" });
        modelList.Add(new dough { Type = "soft" });
        return Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
class dough
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: loadItems">Load</button>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Waste</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableWastes, value: Waste, optionsText: 'Type'"></select></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableWastes = [{ Type: "framed", score: 0 },
                            { Type: "soft", score: 1 },
                            { Type: "unframed", score: 2 }];

    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    var date = new Date();
    self.loadItems = function () {
        var date = new Date();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,

            type: "GET",

            url: "Home/GetItems",

            data: { "date": date },

            success: function (data) {

                var result = "";
                self.items.removeAll();
                $.each(data, function (id, item) {
                    self.items.push({ Waste: item.Type });
                });
            },

            error: function (response) {
                alert('eror');
            }
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to pre-select values.

Update self.items with the Type name and Waste into an observable:

`self.items.push({ Waste: ko.observable(item.Type), Type: item.Type });`

Then use that in the optionsValue binding:

`<select data-bind="options: $root.availableWastes, value: Waste, optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'Type'">`

Screenshot:

[image]